# How to insert data in database through jQuery Ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

[image]Hello stack right now I am facing a problem I am unable to insert data in database through jQuery Ajax I have attached all related files Can anyone go through it I am new in php development.

```
**task.php**

<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

    html, body {
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        background: #fff;
    }

    form {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        padding: 0.25em;
        background: #EEE;

    }

    div {
        padding-bottom: 0.25em;
    }

    /* essential */
    label {
        float: left;
        width: 6em;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 0.5em;
    }

    input, textarea {
        text-align: left;
        width: 200px;
        height:30px;
    }

    input.submit {
        margin-left: 6.5em;
        width: auto;
    }


    label, input.submit {
        font: normal 0.8em Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="insert.js"></script>

<script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>FORM</h1>
<form>
    <div>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="Name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Age:</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Email Id:</label>
        <input type="text" name="emailId" id="emailId"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="pass"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="insertData()" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my insert.php file where I have write all query related to insert my data.

```
**insert.php**

<?php
include("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $Fname=$_POST["name"];
    $Age=$_POST["age"];
    $EmailId=$_POST["emailId"];
    $Password=$_POST["password"];

    $Insert = "INSERT INTO simpleform (Name, Age, Email_Id, Password) 
               VALUES ('.$Fname.', '.$Age.', '.$EmailId.', '.$Password.')";
    $Query=mysqli_query($con, $Insert);

    print_r($Insert);


    if(!$Query) 
    {
        echo mysqli_error();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Successfully Inserted <br />";

    }
}

?>
```

This is my insert.js file where I did all ajax related work.

```
**insert.js**

  function insertData() {
      debugger;
      var name=$("#Name").val();
      var age=$("#age").val();
      var emailId=$("#emailId").val();
      var pass=$("#pass").val();
      debugger;

      // AJAX code to send data to php file.
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "kamalesh/insert.php",
          data: {name:name,age:age,emailId:emailId,pass:pass},
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function(data) {

              alert("Data Inserted");

          }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Can you add a clear explanation of your issue? What do you expect to happen, what is happening, are there any errors? This is so unclear as to what you're asking

Comment: In console my getting proper data but unable to hit my insert.php file

Comment: You need to have a full and proper explanation in your question, we can't do anything with the limited verbal information that you've provided I'm afraid

Comment: Have you tried running the query in phpMyAdmin with similar data?

Comment: Look here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql

Comment: Without using ajax I am able to insert but when I am using jQuery Ajax unable to insert data and no error found.

Comment: Debug your code and share the results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like In your `insert.php` the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` is preventing the script from running when your `insert.js` function passes parameters to `insert.php`. When AJAX passes parameters to `insert.php`, the `isset($_POST['submit'])` will return false.

You will need to remove the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` from `nsert.php`. I will also suggest you to prevent the form from submitting and refreshing your page. Look into `e.preventDefault`.

Also for your $insert query you should remove the "." before and after each variable in the "VALUES". They are not needed.